# Change form action parameter based on PHP array value

Tags: php, arrays, forms, action

I'm trying to create a form in PHP that, when submitted, the URL within action= is altered depending on the option selected.
Code below:

```
$myArray = array(
    '389'=>'Value 1',
    '533'=>'Value 2'
);

echo'<form action="https://example.com/value.php?time=today&value[]='.$num.'" method="post">';
echo'<select name="value">';

foreach($myArray as $num=>$value){
    echo'<option value="'.$num.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}

echo'</select>';
echo'<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
echo'</form>';
```

I think it's not working because the PHP code is being generated before the value has been selected. Not sure if I need to implement some jQuery or Javascript within.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I would use jQuery and manipulate it from the client side.

Comment: You already will pass `$num` within POST array. Why change the `action` url?

Comment: The PHP script runs on the server, and constructs the page before it is sent to the browser. User selections happens in a completely different world. You will have to use something that runs on the browser (javascript).

Comment: You are passing the data to the same `value.php` with or without `$num` in it. How is it different? You get `$num` in the php script anyways, which you can then process.

Comment: Javascript boy,  Javascript.  Use a modern framework like AngularJs or ReactJs.  IMO Jquery is old and complicated, however can do the work if using a framework adds a large load to your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's input and suggestions. I decided to go down the route of some javascript.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var sel = document.getElementById('report');
sel.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("abc").href = "https://example.com/value.php?time=today&value[]=" + this.value + "&date=today";
}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the value of `action` form attribute you have to use javascript.

However, if the example provided is realistic, you can simply change the form method to `GET`:

```
echo'<form action="https://example.com/value.php" method="get">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="time" value="today">';
echo'<select name="value">';

foreach($myArray as $num=>$value){
    echo'<option value="'.$num.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}

echo'</select>';
echo'<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
echo'</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you let the form post naturally, you can get the information you need from the select dropdown. You may need to name your select dropname name="somethingBetter". Please review $_POST and $_GET to understand this better. In your PHP code, use var_dump() to output $_POST and/or $_GET to see what I mean.

If you want a more complex solution. Use jQuery .ajax to fully control where the form will post to. This may be overkill for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated out correctly you have to use some client-side language like JavaScript with jQuery. Here's a quick example how to modify a form's action attribute by selecting an option:

```js
$('#actionSelect').change(function() {
  $form = $('#form');
  console.log(this.value);
  switch (this.value) {
    case "1":
      $form.attr("action", "page1.php");
      break;
    case "2":
      $form.attr("action", "page2.php");
      break;
    case "3":
      $form.attr("action", "page3.php");
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="actionSelect">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<form id="form" action="page1.php">
  <input type="text" name="textInput" />
</form>
```